# Tumblr custom theme disappears when logged out

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I made a custom theme for a client's tumblr, but the blog is not showing up when the viewer is logged out of tumblr. When logged in, it looks perfect. The blog is http://www.openharborpictures.tumblr.com.

It seems to be related to the "Follow openharborpictures" and "Tumblr" buttons that appear at the top right (perhaps something in them is overriding my custom HTML?) but it could also just be a coincidence.  Could not post all of the code, so it's here: http://pastebin.com/U5jctrVK.  Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code. Tumblr inserts more code using server scripts, something you can't do anything about. So for some reason parts of the new code is interfering with your code. It could be the Follow thing you mentioned, but we can't say for sure.

What I would suggest you do is in the custom theme panel, scroll right down to the bottom and click on "Advanced" tab, and then uncheck the "Promote Tumblr" option. This should disable the follow button when you are not signed in to Tumblr.

I can't guarantee that this will solve the problem. But it's worth a try. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That did it! I still have no idea what it could be in there that's making my theme disappear, and not making other people's custom themes disappear (that they know of).  After searching online a lot it seems like it doesn't happen too often-- it may remain a mystery.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what it is either. Maybe just a glitch on Tumblr's part? But I'm glad that it worked anyway. You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Set the body height to 100%

```
body { height: 100% }
```

Comment: So bizarre-- I tried this but it didn't change anything :( Thanks for checking it out though!